# parsing many variables to another file contain many rows

Tags: bash, shell

I have an issue while parsing many variables which extracted by cut command to another file contain many rows, I need to set the variables to the end of each row in sequence.

EX: file 100.txt contain 1000 rows and contain 3 fields A,B,C
another file called pin contain 1000 rows and contain 1 filed 2222

I need to take it one by one and inserted at the end of each row into 100.txt file.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    sed -i "/:[0-9]*$/ ! s%$%,$line%" "100.txt"
done < pin.txt
```

What I have got:

```
1,2,3,2222,3333
1,2,3,2222,3333
```

What I expected:

```
1,2,3,2222
1,2,3,3333
```

Answer (score 1):

If both files have the same number of lines, [`paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) is your friend:

```
paste -d, 100.txt pin.txt > tmp.txt
mv -f tmp.txt 100.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is i would do it using a while read loop without the `sed`

```sh
while IFS= read -r file1 <&3; do
  IFS= read -r file2
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$file1" "$file2"
done 3<100.txt < pin.txt
```

Using `mapfile` `bash4+` only.

```sh
mapfile -t file1 < 100.txt
mapfile -t file2 < pin.txt

for i in "${!file1[@]}"; do
  printf '%s,%s\n' "${file1[$i]}" "${file2[$i]}"
done
```

- Of course those shell loop would be very slow on large data/size files.

Comment: `read -r -u 3 file1` works too instead of doing that input redirection.

Comment: Yes, but that is bashism., also old habits die hard. :-)